# What's the hidden word within the poem?

Tags: word, rhyme, steganography

Hidden within the following poem is a word. I would provide more clue as to how to decipher each letter in the word, but perhaps I'm already giving away too much. Let's see if you can get it!

> If I revealed, in genuine, the depths of my desire,
>
> I’d understand your hesitance, you likely would be shyer.
>
> So I should lie wholeheartedly. But should I? Would I try,
>
> if knowing that there’s one way through – by seeing eye to eye –
>
> and we misstep. There’s nothing left, but dignity. Why lie
>
> when dominance, incontinence are falling rather flat
>
> (just like you) is pretty now at least you aren’t fat.

Comment: Here's a clue: the sentence structure is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Take the number of words in each sentence and use A1Z26 encoding to convert the numbers to letters. Doing so gives SECRET.