# Can you find the hidden word within the poem?

Tags: word, steganography

Within the following poem is a hidden word, with its subsequent letters represented in some way in this poem. Similar to the previous "[find the word in the poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68912/whats-the-hidden-word-within-the-poem)" puzzle (SPOILER).

Here's the poem:

> How
>
> when knowing,
>
> understanding my faults and redresses my halfhearted heart and weak regresses
>
> do you insist on everything, and make sure I’m all right, and sing a stinging song, wrong
>
> why
>
> do you want to cry, every time I write, I lie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hidden word is:

> ACTUAL 
>  
>  Based on the syllable counts of each line and the corresponding letter
>  of the alphabet.
>  
>  1-A  3-C  20-T  21-U  1-A  12-L